# How to validate if label text exists in tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, excel, user-interface, tkinter, label

I'm new to python and I'm wondering how to validate if label text exists. I'm getting an error: 
[image]

Below's my full code. You can see the function `validate` at the bottom, and I'm figuring out how to make the label work in if else condition.

```
import openpyxl, os
import glob
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()

        #Add a widget title
        self.title("Automated filling up of form in iPage")

        #Set widget width and height
        self.minsize(300, 200)

        #Display browse button
        self.displayForm()

    def doubleQuote(self, word):
        return '"%s"' % word

    def displayForm(self):
        #Display label frame
        self.labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Open Excel File")
        self.labelFrame.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=5, sticky=NW)

        #Create browse button
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text = "Browse a File",command = self.openFileDialog)
        self.button.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        ttk.Label(self, text="Cell From:").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Cell To:").grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5)

        self.cf = StringVar()
        self.ct = StringVar()

        self.cellFrom = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.cf)
        self.cellTo = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.ct)

        self.cellFrom.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=5)
        self.cellTo.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=5)

        self.cf.trace("w",self.validate)
        self.ct.trace("w",self.validate)

        self.submitBtn = ttk.Button(self, text='Submit', command=self.validate)
        self.submitBtn.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=5, sticky=NW)


    def openFileDialog(self): 

        #Create a file dialog
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir =  "/", title = "Select A File", filetype =
        [("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls")])

        self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "", textvariable=self.fl)
        self.label.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

        #Change label text to file directory
        self.label.configure(text = self.filename)

        self.label.trace("w",self.validate)

        #Return tail of the path  
        self.trimmed = os.path.basename(self.filename)

        #Pass tail variable
        self.openSpreadsheet(self.trimmed)

    def openSpreadsheet(self, tail): 
        #Open excel spreadsheet
        self.wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(tail)
        self.sheet = self.wb['Sheet1']

        #Return data from excel spreadsheet 
        for rowOfCellObjects in self.sheet[self.cf.get():self.ct.get()]:

            #Loop through data
            for link in rowOfCellObjects:

                #Remove www and firstlightplus.com text
                self.cleanURL = link.value.replace("www.", " ").replace(".firstlightplus.com", "")
                print(self.cleanURL)

    def validate(self, *args):
        #Retrieve the value from the entry and store it to a variable
        if self.cf.get() and self.ct.get() and self.label["text"]:
            print("normal")
            self.submitBtn.config(state='normal')
        else:
            print("disabled")
            self.submitBtn.config(state='disabled')

root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of stacktraces. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format it directly in the question. Pictures of code and error messages aren't searchable and make your question harder to read.

Comment: Okay @BryanOakley

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is the `validate` function can be called before the `openFileDialog` function. This way, the `label` attribute is being accessed before it has been created.

A simple solution would be initialize the attribute in the `displayForm` function:

```py
def displayForm(self):
    #Display label frame
    self.labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Open Excel File")
    self.labelFrame.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=5, sticky=NW)
    self.label = None

    # ... Rest of the code
```

And then, before accessing the attribute, test if it exists:

```py
def validate(self, *args):
    #Retrieve the value from the entry and store it to a variable
    if self.cf.get() and self.ct.get() and self.label and self.label["text"]:
        print("normal")
        self.submitBtn.config(state='normal')
    else:
        print("disabled")
        self.submitBtn.config(state='disabled')
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JUATON-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "ipage.py", line 67, in openFileDialog
    self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "", textvariable=self.fl)
  File "C:\Users\JUATON-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2345, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'fl'`

Comment: Nope, it's different. That's the error I've received.

Comment: That's what I thought. On the code you have provided, you used the propertie `fl` to configure the text variable of a `Label`. However, that property has not been defined on the code provided in the question. If you don't need it, you could just change the creation of the label to: ```self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "", textvariable=self.fl)```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JUATON-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "ipage.py", line 61, in validate
    if self.cf.get() and self.ct.get() and self.label["text"]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: This is what I get now

Comment: @JumarJuaton By the error message, it seems like you did not change the if statement. It should be `if self.cf.get() and self.ct.get() and self.label and self.label["text"]:` instead of `if self.cf.get() and self.ct.get() and self.label["text"]:`.

Comment: Yes! It's now fixed. Thank you for guiding me all throughout.